# How to access files created by another app/created before data wipe in shared storage - Android 11

Tags: java, android, storage

I am trying to add support for Android 11 to two of my apps. Both have the same issue. I really don't want to go for scoped storage as that will take forever to be approved and it is more of a temporary solution and not really doing it properly.

**THE ISSUE: When I create a zip backup of a file, I can list the files and put them into a listview, select and unzip the file. If though I wipe the app data or reinstall it, I can no longer access the files. The list comes up empty.**

I have created a folder in the public libraries, specifically the Documents library.

This is how I do it:

```
Integer num = 0;
        File root,directory, subDirectory;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "Job Cards");
        } else {
            root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "Documents");
            directory = new File(root, "Job Cards");
        }

        subDirectory = new File(directory, "Backups");
        if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdirs();
        if(!subDirectory.exists()) subDirectory.mkdirs();
        try {
            File zipDestination = new File(subDirectory,
                    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US).format(new Date()) +" DataBackup.jcbkp" );
            while(zipDestination.exists()){
                zipDestination =new  File(subDirectory,
                        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US).format(new Date()) + " DataBackup(" + num +").jcbkp" );
                if (zipDestination.exists()){
                    num +=1;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            zipFolder(String.valueOf(getFilesDir()), String.valueOf(zipDestination));
            Toast.makeText(Backup.this, "Backup Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Backup.this, "Failed To Backup!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

This code successfully works to create the files. Now if I need access to them in my app again it works fine, but the moment I do a data wipe for the app or I reinstall the app, even though the files are there I can't access them. I am simply trying to list the files in the directory so that the user can pick which file he wants to restore from. From there I will restore the user's data.

Here is the code I am using to list the files:

```
ArrayList<ObjJob> objFolderList = new ArrayList<>();
        File root,directory, location;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "MTN Job Cards");
        } else {
            root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "Documents");
            directory = new File(root, "MTN Job Cards");
        }

        location = new File(directory, "Backups");
        if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdirs();
        if(!location.exists()) location.mkdirs();

        List fileList = Arrays.asList(location.list());
        Log.d("HOME", "fileList: " + fileList);

        for (Object item : fileList) {
            if (item.toString().contains(".jcbkp")) {
                objFolderList.add(new ObjJob(item.toString()));
            }
        }
```

I have played around and done so much Googling, but I just can't find a solution that works or even where it is discussed. Any help would be incredibly appreciated as I am getting rather annoyed and running out of options to try!

Here is the code for how the Zip folder is generated in case it makes a difference. Grabbed it on stackoverflow:

```
static public void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String destZipFile)
            throws Exception {
        ZipOutputStream zip = null;
        FileOutputStream fileWriter = null;
        fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destZipFile);
        zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);
        addFolderToZip("", srcFolder, zip);
        addFolderToZip("", srcFolder.replace("/files","/shared_prefs"), zip);
        zip.flush();
        zip.close();
    }



    static private void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,
                                     ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception {
        File folder = new File(srcFile);
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip);
        } else if(folder.toString().contains(".png") || folder.toString().contains(".txt") || folder.toString().contains("preferences.xml")){
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
            zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path.replace("/Backup", "") + "/" + folder.getName()));
            //zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                zip.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }

    static private void addFolderToZip(String path, String srcFolder,
                                       ZipOutputStream zip) throws Exception {
        File folder = new File(srcFolder);
        for (String fileName : folder.list()) {
            if (path.equals("")) {
                addFileToZip(folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + fileName, zip);
            } else {
                addFileToZip(path + "/" + folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/"
                        + fileName, zip);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I just can't find a solution that works or even where it is discussed" -- this is expected behavior. You do not have access to other apps' files, which includes prior installations of your own app.

Comment: Libraries? You mean folders i think.

Comment: Ok yes sorry, needs to be "shared storage" which is the term documentation uses. Basically /Documents on the internal storage.